# How to retrieve value of Releation Table's column

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

i am new to hibernate. currently i am stuck in one problem. 
i have no idea how to retrieve the value of relation table column.

```
senario:
i have three tables.
TableA:
-------
a_id
a_col1

TableB:
-------
b_id
b_col1

TableC
-------
c_id
a_id
b_id
c_col1
```

i have created model class for TableA and TableB. i have mapped them using @ManyToMany and @JoinTable annotation

```
TableA
{
    ...
    private Set<TableB> tableB;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable( name="TableC", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id)}
    public getTableB()
    {
        return tableB;
    }
    public setTableB(...) { ... }
}
```

now my question is: 
===================
how can i retrieve the value of **c_col1** from **TableA** entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. What you're seeing is that you don't actually have a many-to-many relationship between A and B. You have three objects: A, B, and C, with a one-to-many from C to A and from C to B. Then your c_col1 column will exist on C.